# Differentiation of $\sin(2x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following question:

> Differentiate $$\sin(2x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$$ with respect to $x$.

My answer is $2\cos(2x) - x^{-3/2}$

There is no final answer to this on the answer sheet, just a breakdown of marks.
Have I answer this correctly or should I have also multiplied $x$ by $2$?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(2x)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}})$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)+\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$$
By the chain rule,
$$2\cos(2x)+\frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$2\cos(2x)+\frac{d}{dx}2x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
By the product rule,
$$2\cos(2x)+2(-\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{3}{2}})$$
$$2\cos(2x)-x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$2\cos(2x)-2x^{-3/2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Do you mean $2\cos(2x)-2x^{-3/2}*\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean! Thank you!